# nested json aggregated rows on group by in postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql, group-by, aggregate

I have a postgresql table

```
alok=# select * from people;
  name   | country |  city   
---------+---------+---------
 alok    | india   | delhi
 ram     | india   | kolkata
 shyam   | india   | kanpur
 krishna | us      | newyork
 ajit    | india   | delhi
 sami    | india   | delhi
 mohamad | india   | kolkata
(7 rows)
```

which can be produced by

```
create table people(name varchar, country varchar, city varchar);

insert into people values('alok', 'india', 'delhi');
insert into people values('ram', 'india', 'kolkata');
insert into people values('shyam', 'india', 'kanpur');
insert into people values('krishna', 'us', 'newyork');
insert into people values('ajit', 'india', 'delhi');
insert into people values('sami', 'india', 'delhi');
insert into people values('mohamad', 'india', 'kolkata');
```

I want to produce aggregated name on country and city like

```
country |                name                
---------+------------------------------------
 india   | {"delhi":["alok", "ajit", "sami"], "kolkata":["ram", "mohamad"], "kanpur":["shyam"]}
 us      | {"newyork":["krishna"]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=694d33eddf26014fa0d5503f068599e1)

```
SELECT 
    country,
    json_object_agg(city, agg_names)
FROM (
    SELECT
        country,
        city, 
        json_agg(name) AS agg_names
    FROM
        people
    GROUP BY country, city
) s
GROUP BY country
```

1. Group the names by `city`. To put the `name`s into one JSON array you can use the aggregate function `json_agg()`
2. Group this result by the `country`. To get the expected output you need to use the aggregate function `json_object_agg()` which creates key/pair values from `city` and `name` array

[documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
   country, json_agg( json_build_object( 'city', city, 'name', name  ) ) 
from (
   select country, city, json_agg( name ) as name
   from people
   group by country, city 
) a 
group by a.country;
```

Comment: Do not post just code. You should also add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: Your code is wrong. You are creating an array finally. This is not what the TO expected. See difference: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=662b6c1ca3a5248b8dc81107462c9bda